# comparing immediate past values to current value in R, missing data too

Tags: r

I am using Rstudio (version .99.903), have a PC (windows 8). I have a question that is really difficult for me. Here is what the data looks like:

```
     Number     Trial       ID  Open date   Enrollment
     420        NCT00091442 9   1/28/2005   0.2
     1476       NCT00301457 26  2/22/2008   1
     10559      NCT01307397 34  7/28/2011   0.6
     6794       NCT00948675 53  5/12/2010   0
     6451       NCT00917384 53  8/17/2010   0.3
     8754       NCT01168973 53  1/19/2011   0.2
     8578       NCT01140347 53  12/30/2011  2.4
     11655      NCT01358877 53  4/2/2012    0.3
     428        NCT00091442 55  9/7/2005    0.1
     112        NCT00065325 62  10/15/2003  0.2
     477        NCT00091442 62  11/11/2005  0.1
     16277      NCT01843374 62  12/16/2013  0.2
     17386      NCT01905657 62  1/8/2014    0.6
     411        NCT00091442 66  1/12/2005   0
```

What I need to do is compare the enrollment of each date within ID to the one prior to it. If there is no date within the ID prior to it, then the comparison should not be made. For instance, for ID  26, there would be no comparison. Similarly, for ID 53, there would be no comparison for 5/12/2010, but I would like to compare 8/17/2010 to 5/12/2010, and then 1/19/2011 to 8/17/2010 (but not also to 5/12/2010). The output would ideally be a dot plot that plots the value of the current against the value of the prior (prior would be on y axis, current on the x axis). Finally, I would need to generate a column that subtracts the current value from the one just prior...

There are >20,000 data points. I've tried to write a script to look back to the prior, but I haven't been been able to control for ID. Also, I imagine it wouldn't be much different if I looked back one year, two years, five years, etc...?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I cannot comprehend what you mean by saying `The output would ideally be a dot plot that plots the value of the current against the value of the prior (prior would be on y axis, current on the x axis)`. What are the current and prior value? Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: so sorry for the confusion - it would be, as in the example above, current would be 8/17/2010 and comparing to prior would be 5/12/2010. Or, 1/19/2011 would be current and 8/17/2010 would be prior. Therefore, the dot plot would place the enrollment value of 8/17/2010 (the prior on the y axis) against the enrollment value of 1/19/2011 (the "current" on the x axis).

Comment: So does that mean you have 0 for y-axis and 97 for x-axis in the case of  8/17/2010  and  5/12/2010?

Comment: sorry i haven't been clear enough, for 8/17/2010, you would have 0.3 and for 5/12/2010 you would have 0. The enrollment is the enrollment rate so i essentially want to create a correlation between the prior enrollment rate and current rate...

Comment: It seems that you want to use `shift()` for `Enrollment` in order to create a graphic. Once you shift values in `Enrollment` you have prior values, which is for y axis. So something like the following would work: `setDT(mydf)[, Opendate := as.IDate(Opendate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")][,prior := shift(Enrollment, type = "lag"), by = ID][,prior := coalesce(prior, 0)]; ggplot(data = mydf, aes(x = Enrollment, y = prior)) + geom_point()`.

Comment: This is absolulely brilliant, thank you Jazzurro!!! One last thing and I will close this out - how can I modify this to, instead of doing the prior comparison, doing one that is 180 days or 365 days, etc...out? E.g., the comparison would be between all of those values within one year before the current value. Does this make sense? Thank you again!!!

Comment: If the date is March 1, 2016, which date would you need for a comparison?

Comment: Would be all dates prior to March 1, 2016 back to a certain predefined amount. For instance, if I wanted to look back 1 year, I would put in March 2, 2015. If 2 years ,then March 2, 2014. etc...

Comment: I am confused about what you described. Did you mean that you want to select all dates (rows) which stays between March 1, 2016 and March 2, 2015, and make comparisons between two dates?

Comment: yes, that is correct. If in the last year, there are no other values for the same ID, then nothing to compare. If one value in the last year, then one value to compare. If two values in the last year, then two values would be compared to the most recent one....

Comment: Would you subset for each date? For example, you have 15 rows in your data set. Would you do the subsetting for each of the 15 rows? This is already getting out of the scope of your question. You may want to look for a post or put this in another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the data process, I think what you want is to get difference in days between two dates. You can achieve this in a few ways. Here, I chose to use `shift()` in the data.table package. You specify `type = "lag"` and in the function and handle subtraction. You do this operation for each ID by specifying `by = ID`. I cannot visualize what kind of plot you have in your mind. I am happy to support you if you can clarify what you meant in your question.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

setDT(mydf)[, Opendate := as.IDate(Opendate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")][,
    out := as.numeric(Opendate - shift(Opendate, type = "lag")), by = ID][,
    out := coalesce(out, 0)]


#    Number       Trial ID   Opendate Enrollment  out
# 1:    420 NCT00091442  9 2005-01-28        0.2    0
# 2:   1476 NCT00301457 26 2008-02-22        1.0    0
# 3:  10559 NCT01307397 34 2011-07-28        0.6    0
# 4:   6794 NCT00948675 53 2010-05-12        0.0    0
# 5:   6451 NCT00917384 53 2010-08-17        0.3   97
# 6:   8754 NCT01168973 53 2011-01-19        0.2  155
# 7:   8578 NCT01140347 53 2011-12-30        2.4  345
# 8:  11655 NCT01358877 53 2012-04-02        0.3   94
# 9:    428 NCT00091442 55 2005-09-07        0.1    0
#10:    112 NCT00065325 62 2003-10-15        0.2    0
#11:    477 NCT00091442 62 2005-11-11        0.1  758
#12:  16277 NCT01843374 62 2013-12-16        0.2 2957
#13:  17386 NCT01905657 62 2014-01-08        0.6   23
#14:    411 NCT00091442 66 2005-01-12        0.0    0
```

DATA

```
mydf <- structure(list(Number = c(420L, 1476L, 10559L, 6794L, 6451L, 
8754L, 8578L, 11655L, 428L, 112L, 477L, 16277L, 17386L, 411L), 
Trial = structure(c(2L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 10L, 11L, 2L), .Label = c("NCT00065325", "NCT00091442", 
"NCT00301457", "NCT00917384", "NCT00948675", "NCT01140347", 
"NCT01168973", "NCT01307397", "NCT01358877", "NCT01843374", 
"NCT01905657"), class = "factor"), ID = c(9L, 26L, 34L, 53L, 
53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 55L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 66L), Opendate = structure(c(3L, 
9L, 12L, 11L, 13L, 2L, 8L, 10L, 14L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("1/12/2005", 
"1/19/2011", "1/28/2005", "1/8/2014", "10/15/2003", "11/11/2005", 
"12/16/2013", "12/30/2011", "2/22/2008", "4/2/2012", "5/12/2010", 
"7/28/2011", "8/17/2010", "9/7/2005"), class = "factor"), 
Enrollment = c(0.2, 1, 0.6, 0, 0.3, 0.2, 2.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 
0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0)), .Names = c("Number", "Trial", "ID", "Opendate", 
"Enrollment"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```